# Automatic Google Spreadsheet Display

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a huge spreadsheet of data on google docs with one of the columns being called "status" which ranges from one star (*) to five stars (*****) for the input. and I want to create a separate sheet that will automatically update showing all data that has been classed as five star "*****".

Any ideas? Sorry I am new to formulas in excel etc.

Comment: @pnuts because It is set to grow larger and will frequently change hence I do not want to have to sort the table, copy and past every day. I would like an automatic update of the statistics I can check quickly and easily :)

Comment: I think i understand the filter now. I could just filter on five stars. I just need to have it live updating from one spreadsheet to another

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Filter function](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en)? It'd definitely slow down for huge files but does dynamically update as the source data set changes.

Comment: That is whatI chose to do Chris yes. Thanks anyway!